# Output a sequence of vector element using cat

Tags: r, cat

I need to get certain output statement using the cat function in R. I wrote the following code

```
it <-1
w <- c(1,2,3)
cat("\nUsing the eq(s)",w,"the iter is:",it,"\n",sep=",")
```

which gives me the following out put

```
Using the eq(s),1,2,3,the iter is:,1,
```

I need to get this output if you can help please

```
Using the eq(s) 1, 2 and 3, the iter is: 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more generalisable (for cases where `length(w) != 3`):

```
enlist <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n <= 1) return(x)
  paste(toString(x[-n]), "and", x[n])
}

cat("Using the eq(s) ", enlist(w), ", the iter is: ", it, "\n", sep = "")
Using the eq(s) 1, 2 and 3, the iter is: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) plain cat**Try it like this:

```
cat("\nUsing the eq(s) ", toString(head(w, -1))," and ", tail(w, 1), 
  ", the iter is: ", it, "\n", sep = "")
```

giving:

```
Using the eq(s) 1, 2 and 3, the iter is: 1
```

**1a)** This variation uses `toString` and then replaces the last comma with `and`.  It has the advantage that it works even if the length of `w` is 1.

```
cat("\nUsing the eq(s) ", sub("(.*),(.*)", "\\1 and \\2", toString(w)),
   ", the iter is: ", it, "\n", sep = "")
```

The remaining solutions could also use this idea but we will show them only as variations of (1).

**2) sprintf** An alternative is to use `sprintf` like this:

```
s <- sprintf("\nUsing the eq(s) %s and %d, the iter is: %d\n", 
       toString(head(w, -1)), tail(w, 1), it)
cat(s)
```

**3) fn$** Another approach is `fn$` in gsubfn.  If one prefaces any function `f` with it as in `fn$f` then string interpolation will be done on the arguments.

```
library(gsubfn)

fn$cat(
  "\nUsing the eq(s) `toString(head(w, -1))` and `tail(w, 1)`, the iter: is $it\n"
)
```